How to train two modules with two different loss in one train_step alternately?
I add two new modules to a large multimodal model. Now, I want to train module A with MSE loss and train module B with CrossEntropy. I've tried to set automatic_optimization to False and process backward manually, but the gradients are always None(I printed gradients with print(param.grad)). Besides,when I train in ddp, I got
RuntimeError: It looks like your LightningModule has parameters that were not used in producing the loss returned by training_step. If this is intentional, you must enable the detection of unused parameters in DDP, either by setting the string value `strategy='ddp_find_unused_parameters_true'` or by setting the flag in the strategy with `strategy=DDPStrategy(find_unused_parameters=True)`.

when I train in deepspeed_stage_2_offload, I got
UserWarning: Detected call of `lr_scheduler.step()` before `optimizer.step()`. In PyTorch 1.1.0 and later, you should call them in the opposite order: `optimizer.step()` before `lr_scheduler.step()`.  Failure to do this will result in PyTorch skipping the first value of the learning rate schedule. See more details at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#how-to-adjust-learning-rate

This might indicate that the optimizer.step() is skipped due to empty gradients.
I configure optimizer with following code:
def configure_optimizers(self):
        def setup_optimizer(param_dict):
            alpha_params = [p for n, p in param_dict.items() if "alpha" in n]
            non_alpha_params = [p for n, p in param_dict.items() if not "alpha" in n]

            optim_groups = [
                {"params": non_alpha_params, "lr": setting.icv_lr},
                {"params": alpha_params, "lr": setting.alpha_lr},
            ]

            if "deepspeed" in setting.strategy:
                optimizer = DeepSpeedCPUAdam(
                    optim_groups,
                    weight_decay=setting.weight_decay,
                )
            else:
                optimizer = optim.Adam(
                    optim_groups,
                    weight_decay=setting.weight_decay,
                )

            step_batches = self.trainer.estimated_stepping_batches
            warmup_steps = setting.warmup_step
            if isinstance(warmup_steps, float):
                warm_steps = warmup_steps * step_batches
            elif isinstance(warmup_steps, int):
                warm_steps = warmup_steps
            else:
                raise ValueError(
                    f"the warm_steps should be int or float, but got {type(warmup_steps)}"
                )
            scheduler = get_cosine_schedule_with_warmup(
                optimizer, num_warmup_steps=warm_steps, num_training_steps=step_batches
            )
            return {
                "optimizer": optimizer,
                "lr_scheduler": {"scheduler": scheduler, "interval": "step"},
            }

        attn_shift_opt = setup_optimizer(self.shift_encoder.attn_shift_params())
        if Stratety.ALTERNATE_TRAINING in self.strategy:
            ffn_shift_opt = setup_optimizer(self.shift_encoder.ffn_shift_params())
            return attn_shift_opt, ffn_shift_opt
        return attn_shift_opt

In my train step:
def optimize(opt, sch, loss_dict):
          loss_dict = {
              k: v / setting.accumulate_grad_batches for k, v in loss_dict
          }
          self.manual_backward(sum(loss_dict.values()))
          if (batch_idx + 1) % setting.accumulate_grad_batches == 0:
              self.clip_gradients(
                  opt,
                  gradient_clip_val=setting.grad_clip_val,
                  gradient_clip_algorithm="norm",
              )
              opt.step()
              sch.step()
              opt.zero_grad()
          return loss_dict
          
      attn_opt, shift_opt = self.optimizers()
      attn_sch, shift_sch = self.lr_schedulers()


      loss_dict = {
          **optimize(
              attn_opt,
              attn_sch,
              self.layer_wise_forward(query_inputs, ice_hidden_states),
          ),
          **optimize(
              shift_opt,
              shift_sch,
              self.task_specific_forward(
                  query_inputs, ice_logits, ice_label_mask
              ),
          ),
      }

How to resolve this issue?
